# How to toggle "reduce motion" preference with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I'd like to be able to toggle the macOS "reduce motion" preference (system preferences > accessibility > display > display > reduce motion) via the touchbar analogous to this [article about toggling dark mode](https://atechguides.org/how-to-toggle-macos-catalinas-dark-mode/) Does anyone have an idea on how to toggle it with AppleScript? I googled around a bit, but came up empty handed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This AppleScript code works for me using the latest version of macOS Catalina

```
if application "System Preferences" is running then ¬
    do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
repeat until application "System Preferences" is not running
    delay 0.1
end repeat

tell application "System Preferences"
    reveal anchor "Seeing_Display" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.universalaccess"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists of checkbox "Reduce motion" of tab group 1 of ¬
        group 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click checkbox "Reduce motion" of tab group 1 of ¬
        group 1 of window "Accessibility" of application process "System Preferences"
end tell
tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```